# Ordering by object.count in PFQueryTableViewController

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I need to query all objects in a class and order them all by the frequency of each object in Swift. I'm getting the query using...

```
// Define the query that will provide the data for the table view
    override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery{
        var query = PFQuery(className: "Upvotes")
        return query
    }
```

...but can't seem to retrieve an objects.count item since I can't use an async completion block with a `findObjectsInBackground` call. Is this something I should handle in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath()`?

Comment: why can't you use async completion block?

Comment: I think you can use completion block, and inside that reload TableView

Comment: Because I need to return the query, and use object["key"] in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` that I get from the return. Can't get those objects from a `findObjectsInBackground()` as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 0):

But you can do something like this:

```
class demo: UIViewController {

    var parseObjects: NSArray!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    }

    // Define the query that will provide the data for the table view

    func yourQuery() -> PFQuery {
        var query = PFQuery(className: "Upvotes")

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                if (objects!.count > 0) {
                    parseObjects = objects //Store those objects in your variable
                }

            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                println("Error: \(error) \(error!.userInfo!)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and after that in your tableViewDelegate use parseObjects variable...

Comment: Like I said, I can't do that. The function must `return query`. I can of course just use a standard `UITableView`, but I was looking to use a `PFQueryTableViewController` for simplicity's sake. I guess I'll have to resort to the former.

Comment: hoping this will help https://parse.com/questions/using-pfquerytableviewcontroller-for-uitableview-sections